# ClientRequestFilter vs ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I knew filters are used to handle the request and can do things with http header and httpmethods, but am confused with

**What is the difference between `ClientRequestFilter` and `ContainerRequestFilter`?
In which scenario we have to use `ClientRequestFilter` and `ContainerRequestFilter`?**

I tried with [this website](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e6547) but not any details about this.

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two side to a REST interaction, the client and the server. Jersey/JAX-RS-2 has both a Client API and the "main" Server side API. When working with the Client API, we could use the `ClientRequestFilter`, and when using the Server Side API, we would use the `ContainerRequestFilter`. There's no possibility to mix and match these, they should strictly be used with the appropriate side of the interaction.

A `ContainerRequestFilter` (Server Side) example would be to do some authorization/authentication, which a pretty common use case for server side filter. The filter will be invoked before reaching any of your resources

```
Client --->  Internet ---> Server ---> Filter ---> Resource
```

A `ClientRequestFilter` (Client Side) example would be implement some client side cache (sort of mocking a browser cache). Or a a case (which already has been implemented) is a filter to encode a user name and password for BASIC authentication. Before the request actually gets sent to the server, the client filter will get invoked.

```
Client ---> Filter ---> Internet ---> Server ---> Resource
```

---

There are also `XxxResponseFilters` that follow the following flow

```
Resource ---> ContainerResponseFilter ---> Server ---> Internet ---> Client

Server ---> Internet ---> ClientResponseFilter ---> Client
```

Comment: I have a set of filters that implements ClientRequestFilter, without registering it is automatically got invoked. Is there any way to skip certain filters based on the condition?