# Moving ClientFilter from Jersey to Jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to migrate the usages of Jersey Client in my codebase from `com.sun.jersey.client` to `org.glassfish.jersey.client`.

In multiple parts of the codebase I am creating classes that inherit from `ClientFilter` and override the `handle` method.

What is the replacement of `ClientFilter` in Jersey 2 and how should I change the places I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Jersey docs section [Client Filters](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9473). Basically there are `ClientRequestFilter` and `ClientResponseFilter`. The former is called before the request goes out and the latter is called on the incoming response. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27578248/2587435) for more info on the flow.